# Is there any NPM for MapMyIndia?

Tags: node.js, npm, reverse-geocoding, npm-request, mapmyindia-api

For a node.js project, I want to use reverse geocoding with mapMyIndia API, but couldn't find any proper package for that.

PS: I don't want to use API directly in my code, appreciate the help

Comment: Not a programming question....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use this package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapmyindia-sdk-nodejs
I made this package few days back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapmyIndia Official package here.
https://www.npmjs.com/org/mapmyindia

For Map to develop Hybrid App:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapmyindia-map-cordova-ionic-beta